# Inserting date sometimes inserts all 0's

Tags: php, mysql

i have a column in my database for the date a new record was added, it's set with the following code:

```
    $dateset = date("Y-m-d");
    $q = "INSERT INTO appts (date_set) VALUES ('$dateset')";
```

this is working about 80% of the time, is there any reason that randomly it will add the date as "0000-00-00"?

Comment: Is `$dateset` 100% surely not empty or invalid? Is the code literally like this, or does `$dateset` come from somewhere else?

Comment: You get '0000-00-00' when you try to insert an invalid date. You should probably look for other places in your app which insert records in that table. Your code looks fine, but if you want to be extra sure you can use `...VALUES (NOW())`.

Comment: @deceze this is literally the code. this is the only time `$dateset` is ever used

Comment: Ugh, do use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL injection and other nasties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check type of field 'date_set'.

- if type is DATE you have to use:

```
    $dateset =  date("Y-m-d");
```

- if type is DATETIME you have to use:

```
    $dateset =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    //It is correct, but database push after time 00:00:00 (but it depends on the settings of the database)
    //$dateset =  date("Y-m-d");
```

- if type is TIMESTAMP you have to use:

```
    $dateset =  time();
```

Try use sql:

```
    $q = "INSERT INTO appts (date_set) VALUES (NOW())";
```

Comment: (NOW()) is what i'll use

Answer (score 1):

I think it would the best decision to use

`$q = "INSERT INTO appts (date_set) VALUES (NOW())";`

Answer (score 0):

> is there any reason that randomly it will add the date as "0000-00-00"?

No.

Either `$dateset` populated some other way or value got updated to 0's later on.

Comment: That's why I'm so confused. $dateset is never mentioned anywhere else in the entirety of the code. I'll probably have to just use NOW